# AddDbContext not working in ConfigureServices of ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I reversed a SQL server database into their respective classes and context, and all this appears to of worked fine.

In the min context class, there is a line of code pointing to the connection string, which if left in works fine, but the connection string is fully embedded in the context file.

I tried commenting it out of the context and adding via the `ConfigureServices` section (so I can use the `conn` string in *appsettings.json*) using

```
services.AddDbContext<myDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("dbconn")));
```

But when I run, I get an error:-

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No database provider has been
> configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by
> overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext
> on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then
> also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a
> `DbContextOptions<TContext>` object in its constructor and passes it to
> the base constructor for DbContext.'

I have tried numerous things on Google but I always end up with the same error, unless I uncomment the hard-coded connection string in the context class file.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

I have tried many many Google responses and all have the same error - the:-

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No database provider has been
> configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by
> overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext
> on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then
> also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a
> `DbContextOptions<TContext>` object in its constructor and passes it to
> the base constructor for DbContext.'

I comment this out from the context class:-

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=MYSERVER\\MSSQL2017EXPRESS;Database=DBNAME;Trusted_Connection=True;user id=DBUSER;password=DBPASSWORD;");
```

And this is what is in startup.cs but not working:-

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });
   services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    //My DB conn
    services.AddDbContext<myDatabaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("dbconn")));

}
```

I need to be able to provide the connection string from *appsettings.json* and not have it hard coded in to the context class file.

Comment: How can you retrieve the options from the database before you make a connection?  You need the options to make the connection.  The options has to be in the c# project, not the database.

Comment: If AddDbContext is used, then also **ensure that your DbContext type accepts a  `DbContextOptions<TContext>` object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.**'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely missing a constructor on your context.

```
public myDatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<myDatabaseContext> options) : base(options) {
    //...
}
```

as advised in the error message

> If `AddDbContext` is used, then
>   also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a
>   `DbContextOptions<TContext>` object in its constructor and passes it to
>   the base constructor for `DbContext`.'

Answer (score -1):

You are most likely missing the package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.

Comment: No, the code wouldn't even compile then.